# Работа с COM портом. Разница между flush и discard

Tags: linux, com-port, перевод

В Windows есть функция `PurgeComm`

> Discards all characters from the output or input buffer of a specified communications resource. It can also terminate pending read or write operations on the resource.

и есть функция `FlushFileBuffers`

> Flushes the buffers of a specified file and causes all buffered data to be written to a file.

Тут все понятно `PurgeComm` очищает буфер, а `FlushFileBuffers` заставляет сбросить данные с буфера на файл.

Теперь Linux. `int tcflush(int fd, int queue_selector);`

`man termios` выдает следующее:

> tcflush() discards data written to the object referred to by fd but not transmitted, or data received but not read, depending on the value of queue_selector:
>
> TCIFLUSH - flushes data received but not read.
>
> TCOFLUSH - flushes data written but not transmitted.
>
> TCIOFLUSH - flushes both data received but not read, and data written but not transmitted.

То есть в описании функции сказано что она **discards**, а в описании флагов 
**flushes**

Так в итоге что она делает? Удаляет данные из буфера или сбрасывает их в файл?

Comment: Flush -- это слив сливного бочка. О каком вообще файле вы говорите?

Comment: Я вашего комментария вообще не понял, о каком сливном бочке вы говорите? Здесь немного другая тематика

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> То есть в описании функции сказано что она discards, а в описании флагов flushes
>
> Так в итоге что она делает? Удаляет данные из буфера или сбрасывает их в файл?

Не вижу здесь разночтений или противоречий, в описании написано отбрасывает (*discards*), значит отбрасывает. Конечно по аналогии с Си'шной `fflush()` из `stdio` можно было бы подумать, что данные куда-то запишутся, а не просто очистится буфер, однако строго говоря, сам термин «*flush*» без контекста ни коим образом не говорит об этом, в документации в таких случаях обычно пишут что-то вроде «*flushes to ...*»

Аналогом `FlushFileBuffers` традиционно является семейство системных вызовов `sync()`, а точнее `fsync()`/`fdatasync()`.